# #include "unpipc.h" in c no such file or directory

Tags: c, unix, posix

```
#include "unpipc.h"
```

I am trying to use `#include "unpipc.h"` with cygwin but it gives me an error not such file or directory
I tried to write it as `#include <unpipc.h>` but still the error occur.

the code is in C language.

Comment: Where is that file? Is that directory on the default include path or specified with a `-I` flag?

Comment: That's not a standard header file, you need to download it from the web site for the Unix Network Programming book. http://www.kohala.com/start/unpv22e/unpv22e.html

Comment: There's no such header file in "standard" POSIX environment. What functionality (what functions) do you expect to find in the file?

Comment: Hmm, usually `.h` files (functions declarations and macro definitions) go with their `.c` counterparts (functions definitions) or precompiled libraries.

Answer (score 1):

As has been noted, that is not a standard file

```
$ curl 'cygwin.com/cgi-bin2/package-grep.cgi?text=1&arch=x86_64&grep=unpipc.h'
Found 0 matches for unpipc.h
```